# Equivalent of return in lua?

Tags: lua

I have a loop in lua and when a certain thing happens I want it to start the loop over. However when I do return it just ends the loop.

```
wrong = false
while true do
    if wrong then
      return
    end

    print 'Not wrong'
end
```

Comment: Are you looking for a "continue" keyword? If so, you may want to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3524970/why-does-lua-have-no-continue-statement

Comment: `return` is doing exactly what it's supposed to do. In most languages `return` terminates the current function call, not just the current loop. I suggest you rewrite the question to describe what you want to do, rather than what you incorrectly think `return` should do.

Answer (score 2):

First of all `return` does not terminate your loop, it terminates the entire function / script. Be aware of that! To terminate a loop use `break`. You are looking for an equivalent to "continue" in other languages.

There is no such thing in Lua. You could fiddle something together using `goto` statements which are available in newer Lua versions but in general you could simply rewrite your code:

```
while true do
  if not wrong then
    print("not wrong")
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Return terminates a function and returns a value. I believe you want to `break` out of a loop

Comment: `break` doesn't start the loop over, which is what the OP asked about.