# Break while loop on Lua if condition is not met

Tags: lua

I have this simple while loop. I'd like to make it break the loop when the conditional variable is changed. Instead, it's finishing the loop and only then breaking it.

```
a = true
while( a == true )
do
  center_general_medium:highlight(1)
  center_general_small:highlight(1)
  center_general_tiny:highlight(1)
  a = false << ------------------- should break loop here if, for some reason, "a" value is changed.
  center_general_medium:highlight(1)
  center_general_small:highlight(1)
  center_general_tiny:highlight(1)
end
```

Comment: Unless I've missed something, isn't this a simple `break` statement: `if (false == a) break` (or something similar)?

Comment: In that case, would I have to repeat that condition before every action inside the loop? I mean, let's say I had functions that could change "a" value instead of those highlight commands. If in the first function "a" value is changed, it would not break the loop; it'd finish it before breaking.

Comment: Yes indeed.  Alternatively, you could do: `if (true == a) center_general_medium:highlight(1)` on each line

Comment: There is no other solution, right?

Comment: Sounds like you want `continue` functionality, which is similar to a `break`. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3524970/why-does-lua-have-no-continue-statement

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: no, that's just not how loops work.

---

Long answer: Technically, you could do this with lots of magic, but it wouldn't look pretty. Coroutines and metamethods can take you a long way, if you're willing to put some work into it, but I don't think it's worth it in your example.

Looking at your problem, it's obvious that you actually have an inner and an outer loop; the outer one being the `while` loop, and the inner just looping over a few objects and calling `:highlight(1)` on them. So what you *really* want, is to `break` through two loops at once, which can't be done. Instead, you should write the inner loop as an actual loop, and break out of that when `a == false`, then let the outer loop stop because of the unmet condition.

```lua
local objects = {
   center_general_medium,
   center_general_small,
   center_general_tiny,
   center_general_medium,
   center_general_small,
   center_general_tiny
}

a = true

while a do
   for _, object in ipairs(objects) do
      object:highlight(1)
      if not a then break end
   end
end
```