# Lua goto statement to simulate continue raised error

Tags: lua, continue

Generally, my goal is to simulate the continue statement, which doesn't exist in Lua. I have read some thread about using goto to do this. I tried:

```
for i=0, 9, 1 do
    if i<5 then goto skip end
    print(i)
    ::skip::
end
```

It raised "lua: test.lua:2: '=' expected near 'skip'"

Is there any workaround to this? Thanks in advance

Comment: What version of Lua are you using? Are you sure it's 5.2?

Comment: I'm using version 5.1, is it already available then?

Comment: Oh based on the reference its just added since 5.2. My bad.

Comment: Is there any way to achieve the same thing with my current version? @NicolBolas

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can simulate `continue` (to a degree) using a combination of `repeat .... until true` and `break` (works with Lua 5.1+):

```
for i=0, 9, 1 do repeat
    if i<5 then break end
    print(i)
until true end
```

Note that it makes `break` behave as `continue`, so you can't use it with its normal meaning. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3524970/why-does-lua-have-no-continue-statement) for further details and alternative solutions.

Comment: This is what im looking for! Thank you sir

Answer (score 1):

The `goto` statement is not supported by Lua 5.1 (and older) as well as not by LuaJIT which I consider real issue. Following code wraps the code which is subject to continue statement into an **anonymous function** - which I consider better readable but also your original iteration code remains almost unchanged.

```lua
for i = 0, 9, 1 do
  (function()
     if i < 5 then return end
     print(i)
  end)()
end
```

Comment: Your answer does not address the question posed by the author.

The question is about an equivalent of the `continue` statement, but your code effectively performs a `break` when the `if` succeeds.

Comment: Correctly, the anonymous function should  encapsulate only the code which is subject to `continue` statement